# MATLAB callback notification when title bar of figure is clicked

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-figure

What I am searching for is a function under MATLAB which is triggered when I click on a title bar of the figure window.

Unfortunately the `WindowButtonUpFcn` of MATLAB does only work within a figure but not when clicking on the title bar. This is valid for R2007b but also for R2016b, so I assume this behaviour is existing for all MATLAB releases.

Several attempts to use the underlying Java framework didn't work for me, like this one:

```
hFig = figure
jFig = get(hFig, 'JavaFrame');
fpc = get(jFig, 'FigurePanelContainer');
set(fpc, 'MouseReleasedCallback', @callback_mouseReleased);
```

Does somebody have a solution for it, wether using documented or as tried above even undocumented features of MATLAB?

Best regards,
Domenico